# Displaying hours and minutes on x-axis with Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to output the following data (time, battery level) in a area chart:

```
data: [
    [08.15, 14.8],
    [08.20, 13.9],
    [08.25, 12.8],
    [08.30, 11.8],
    [08.35, 13.9],
    [08.40, 14.1],
    [08.45, 13.9],
    [08.50, 14],
    [08.55, 14],
    [09.00, 14.1],
    [09.05, 14.4]
]
```

the x-axis should start at 00.00 am AM 00.00 PM, a whole day.

Unfortunately I do not understand which options to use, when I review the API. 
What I get now is an x-axis that goes from 8.00~8.55,8.60,8.65 ~ 9.00. So it uses a decimal system instead of a minute system.

How do I configure that the line should consist of 24 hours with 60 minutes?

With the current data, the chart would be kind of empty, only having points around 8.00am to 9.00 am.

I hope someone can help me on my way.

Thanks,

Mattijs

Comment: What are your x-axis values? You want them to span from midnight to midnight, but only want to show between 8:15 and 9:05?

Comment: Hey Matt did you found the solution? cause i am trying to achieve the same

Answer (score 33):

you can try this code to make x-axis in 12hour time format

```
xAxis: {
    title: {
        enabled: true,
        text: 'Hours of the Day'
    },
    type: 'datetime',

    dateTimeLabelFormats : {
        hour: '%I %p',
        minute: '%I:%M %p'
    }
},
```

Also for "tooltip" try this:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return ''+
                "" +
                'Time: '+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%I:%M %p', this.x);
    }
},
```

And of course series would be:

```
series: [{
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2013, 3, 22, 1, 15), 12.7], 
            [Date.UTC(2012, 3, 24, 3, 20), 13.5], 
            [Date.UTC(2012, 2, 22, 2, 25), 18.8]
        ]
    }]
```

Hope it could solve your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Highcharts has a built in way of plotting times or dates as the xaxis. Typically, in this case, your data would use a time value in milliseconds, and highcharts will plot it accordingly ([see this example](http://jsfiddle.net/CAKQH/310/)).

If you wanted to have a 24 hour day including your data, it might look something like this:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime' //ensures that xAxis is treated as datetime values
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2012, 5, 22, 8, 15), 14.8], 
            [Date.UTC(2012, 5, 22, 8, 20), 13.9], 
            [Date.UTC(2012, 5, 22, 8, 25), 12.8]
            //and so on...
        ]
    }]
});
```

You could then do something like use a custom [xAxis formatter](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis-labels--formatter) or [date formatter](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis--dateTimeLabelFormats) to display the labels however you want.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I will try and put it in practice.

Comment: Sadly, the solution provided does not work when the dates are completely different (ie. when the year, month or day changes between samples of the data array). Does anyone know how can I pass different dates and just draw the hours on the x-axis? I have tried formatting with both dateTimeLabelFormats and Highcharts.dateFormat and it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The last links are dead.